# Слишком медленный поиск на сайте. Как его можно ускорить?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ajax, ecommerce

Есть корпоративный сайт: https://evroflag.by/. Сайт сделан на Wordpress. Тема Woodmart.
Но почему-то на нем **слишком медленный поиск** (тот что в header). Буду очень благодарен, если кто-то поможет советом, как его можно ускорить. Это связано с AJAX?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://kagg.eu/profiling-wordpress-sites-meetup-materials/ https://wpmag.ru/2014/profilirovanie-koda-v-wordpress/

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.